# I'm throwing and error using mysqli prepared statements on an insert into my DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Based on an earlier post I'm trying to learn prepared statements to sanitize everything properly.

Here's my form:

```
<form name="login" action="regi.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label for="username">Username: </label><br />
            <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Handle" required><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="sign_up_date" value="<?php echo $_POST['sign_up_date'] ?>">
        <label for="usermail">Email: </label><br />
            <input type="email" name="usermail" placeholder="yourname@email.com" required><br />
        <label for="password">Password: </label><br />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Here's the regi.php page:

```
include("mysql_connect.php");
include("classes/insert.php");


if (!mysqli_query($mysqli,$stmt))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Here is my insert.php page:

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['usermail'];

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Init failed";
} else {
    $cmd = "INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW() )";
    if ($stmt->prepare($cmd)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssd', $user, $email );
        $stmt->execute();

        echo $stmt->affected_rows . "row(s) inserted";

        $stmt->close();

    } else {
        echo "Prepare failed";
    }   
}
```

Here is my error message:

Localhost via UNIX socket 0row(s) insertedError:

I assume i'm doing something wrong on my insert.php page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 'ssd', but only two string variables?

Comment: Should i only use 'ss'?

Comment: well, SS seemed to work fine... Does everything else look properly sanitized?

Comment: You have 2 parameters (question marks) in your INSERT statement and you are trying to biind 3 variables

Answer (score 0):

you could write your query as a stored procedure ... this way the actual query is stored in the db and not in your php file.

also, based on what you have right now it does not look like you are inserting the correct values into the right columns in your table

here is the stored procedure approach

// update your php files so that the following variables read

```
$cmd = call `people`.`procedurename` (?,?)";
$stmt->bind_param($user, $email );
```

log into mysql and create a stored procedure with this code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `people`.`procedurename` (
IN username VARCHAR(50),
IN email VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO people (username, email, sign_up_date) VALUES (username, email, NOW());
END
$$
```

good luck :)